# I keep getting java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' error although it has already confirmed they is a user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have relatively new to Fire Base implementation. I have done the same thing over and over and it works yet now when I use it fails. The error comes in when I am trying to retrieve data from database the app crashes saying nullpoint error getUid(), I will post the error below. The error comes up after I have already logged in and verified that the is a user.

Here is the code:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button UpdateAccountSettings;
    private EditText UserName, UserStatus;
    private CircleImageView UserProfileImage;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    private DatabaseReference RootRef;

    private String currentUserID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        currentUserID = currentUser.getUid();

        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://chatrcsapp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").getReference();

        IntializeFields();


        

        UpdateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UpdateSettings();
            }
        });


        RetrieveUserInfo();

    }





    private void IntializeFields() {

        UpdateAccountSettings = findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
        UserName = findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        UserStatus = findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
        UserProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    }

    private void UpdateSettings() {
        String setUserName = UserName.getText().toString();
        String setUserStatus = UserStatus.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Insert User Name, please...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserStatus)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Insert User Status, please...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
            profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
            profileMap.put("status", setUserStatus);

            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            SendUserToMainActivity();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Details Added Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
    private void RetrieveUserInfo() {
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")))){

                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveUserProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                            UserName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            UserStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);


                        }
                        else if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name"))){

                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            UserName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            UserStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);
                        }
                        else{

                            UserName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please Update your Information...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainActivity= new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainActivity);
        finish();
    }
    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }
    

}
```

And here is the error message:

```
    Process: com.arthur.chatapp, PID: 8049
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arthur.chatapp/com.arthur.chatapp.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2944)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3079)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6711)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.arthur.chatapp.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3079) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1836) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6711) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

Comment: Your currentUser is null, which is a common case.  Read this: [Why is my currentUser == null?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explicit:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
>    at com.arthur.chatapp.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:49)
> ```

So no matter what you may think, in whic code the `currentUser` really is `null`.

```
currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
currentUserID = currentUser.getUid();
```

Most likely this is because Firebase hasn't set `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` yet by the time your code runs. To prevent this, you can use an auth state listener that ensures your code automatically gets run whenever the authentication state changes:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://chatrcsapp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").getReference();

    IntializeFields();        
    UpdateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UpdateSettings();
        }
    });

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            currentUserID = currentUser.getUid();
            if (user != null ) {
                RetrieveUserInfo();
            } else { //user is not logged in
                ...
            }
        }
    });
};
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I have already tried that but the app does go the settingsActivity from the MainActivity but when I updatesettings(); it crashes, meaning it does not retrieve data from Firebase but run it activity as empty.

Comment: My answer focuses on `SettingsActivity.onCreate`, because that is the stack trace in your question. With my answer that specific stack trace should have disappeared. Is that the case? If so, this answers the errror you posted about in this question.
The fundamental problem in other places is likely the same as the one I explained in my answer: you can't rely on `getCurrentUser()` return you an actual user in most places, and will need to put it in an auth state listener.